# Which full node implementation(s) supports SegWit

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, bitcore

I just finished setting up a full node using [bitcore.io's guide here](https://bitcore.io/guides/full-node). I need my node to support SegWit though and I am not entirely sure whether what I have set up offers SegWit support. Especially after reading this article: [What Bitcore Users Need to Know To Be Ready for Segwit Activation](https://blog.bitpay.com/bitcore-segwit-activation/).

Is this the correct choice of a full node platform for me to have SegWit? What other options do I have?

Note: I have a wallet based on [Copay](https://github.com/bitpay/copay) who's builders also maintain bitcore.io so their full node software was my first/obvious choice

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core has supported segwit for a long time and will have decent segwit support in the GUI/RPC in version 0.16 which is going to be released hopefully within the next couple of weeks. Knots also supports segwit, as does btcd I believe. Others like bcoin probably do too but I'm not sure, someone else might know better

You can look at this page for some general ideas: https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_adoption/